# Computer Rental Problem - Linear Optimization in Pyomo. My solution Runs in AMPL but Pyomo says it has no Bound - What could be wrong

Tags: python, linear-programming, pyomo, ampl

I am trying to model a simple Linear Problem in Pyomo. I completed the modeling in AMPL and got the right answer but for some weird reason, Pyomo says it has no bounds.

If someone could be kind enough to eyeball what I did to see why it does not work in pyomo. All the data and code are below.

**THIS IS THE ORIGINAL PROBLEM:** BCoE has determined that during each of the next 12 months it will need the number of laptop computers given in the table below. To meet these requirements, the BCoE rents laptops for a period of one, two, or three months. It costs $100 to rent a laptop for one month, $180 for two months, and $250 for three months. At the beginning of month 1, BCOE has 70 laptops. Determine the rental plan that meets the next 12 months’ requirements at a minimum cost. Write out a mathematical program for this problem and solve it using a solver of your choice.

| Month | Laptop Requirement |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 700 |
| 2 | 1100 |
| 3 | 500 |
| 4 | 600 |
| 5 | 1100 |
| 6 | 500 |
| 7 | 700 |
| 8 | 700 |
| 9 | 300 |
| 10 | 600 |
| 11 | 700 |
| 12 | 700 |

**THIS IS WHAT I CODED IN PYOMO:**

```
# IMPORT THE NECESSARY CLASSES
from pyomo.environ import *
infinity = float('inf')

# CREATE THE MODEL
model=ConcreteModel()


# GENERAL VARIABLES:
borrowPeriod = [1,2,3]   # Number of Months you can Borrow The laptops
Months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]  # Ind
demandPerMonth = [700,1100,500,600,1100,500,700,700,300,600,700,700]


# Variables Month1 - Month12 are meant to just know which Indices to use for each Month when I code the constraints

Month1 = []
for i in range(1,2):
    for j in borrowPeriod:
        tmp = i,j
        Month1.append(tmp)        

Month2 = []
for i in range(1,3):
    for j in borrowPeriod:
        tmp = i,j
        Month2.append(tmp)

Month2 = Month2[-5:]


Month3 = []
for i in range(1,4):
    for j in borrowPeriod:
        tmp = i,j
        Month3.append(tmp)

Month3 = Month3[-5:]
Month3.append(Month1[-1])


Month4 = []
for i in range(1,5):
    for j in borrowPeriod:
        tmp = i,j
        Month4.append(tmp)

Month4 = Month4[-5:]
Month4.append(Month2[-1])


Month5 = []
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in borrowPeriod:
        tmp = i,j
        Month5.append(tmp)

Month5 = Month5[-5:]
Month5.append(Month3[-2])


Month6 = []
for i in range(1,7):
    for j in borrowPeriod:
        tmp = i,j
        Month6.append(tmp)

Month6 = Month6[-5:]
Month6.append(Month4[-2])


Month7 = []
for i in range(1,8):
    for j in borrowPeriod:
        tmp = i,j
        Month7.append(tmp)

Month7 = Month7[-5:]
Month7.append(Month5[-2])


Month8 = []
for i in range(1,9):
    for j in borrowPeriod:
        tmp = i,j
        Month8.append(tmp)

Month8 = Month8[-5:]
Month8.append(Month6[-2])


Month9 = []
for i in range(1,10):
    for j in borrowPeriod:
        tmp = i,j
        Month9.append(tmp)

Month9 = Month9[-5:]
Month9.append(Month7[-2])


Month10 = []
for i in range(1,11):
    for j in borrowPeriod:
        tmp = i,j
        Month10.append(tmp)

Month10 = Month10[-5:]
Month10.append(Month8[-2])


Month11 = []
for i in range(1,12):
    for j in borrowPeriod:
        tmp = i,j
        Month11.append(tmp)

Month11 = Month11[-5:]
Month11.append(Month9[-2])


Month12 = []
for i in range(1,13):
    for j in borrowPeriod:
        tmp = i,j
        Month12.append(tmp)

Month12 = Month12[-5:]
Month12.append(Month10[-2])


# FULLDATA is meant to hold all actual variables I would be manipulating in the constraints and Objective Function.

fullData = []
for i in Months:
    for j in borrowPeriod:
        tmp = i,j
        fullData.append(tmp)

fullData
model.full = Var(fullData, initialize=0)



# THE OBJECTIVE FUNCTION:
model.value = Objective(expr = 100*sum(model.full[x] for _,x in enumerate(fullData) if x[1] == 1) + 180*sum(model.full[x] for _,x in enumerate(fullData) if x[1] == 2) + 250*sum(model.full[x] for _,x in enumerate(fullData) if x[1] == 3), sense=minimize)



# THE CONSTRAINTS - These Contraints are as per the question

model.month1 = Constraint(expr = 70 + sum(model.full[x] for _,x in enumerate(Month1)) >= 700)
model.month2 = Constraint(expr = sum(model.full[x] for _,x in enumerate(Month2)) >= 1100)
model.month3 = Constraint(expr = sum(model.full[x] for _,x in enumerate(Month3)) >= 500)
model.month4 = Constraint(expr = sum(model.full[x] for _,x in enumerate(Month4)) >= 600)
model.month5 = Constraint(expr = sum(model.full[x] for _,x in enumerate(Month5)) >= 1100)
model.month6 = Constraint(expr = sum(model.full[x] for _,x in enumerate(Month6)) >= 500)
model.month7 = Constraint(expr = sum(model.full[x] for _,x in enumerate(Month7)) >= 700)
model.month8 = Constraint(expr = sum(model.full[x] for _,x in enumerate(Month8)) >= 700)
model.month9 = Constraint(expr = sum(model.full[x] for _,x in enumerate(Month9)) >= 300)
model.month10 = Constraint(expr = sum(model.full[x] for _,x in enumerate(Month10)) >= 600)
model.month11 = Constraint(expr = sum(model.full[x] for _,x in enumerate(Month11)) >= 700)
model.month12 = Constraint(expr = sum(model.full[x] for _,x in enumerate(Month12)) >= 700)
```

**THIS IS THE RESULT I GET**

```
[    0.00] Setting up Pyomo environment
[    0.00] Applying Pyomo preprocessing actions
[    0.01] Creating model
[    0.01] Applying solver
[    0.05] Processing results
    Number of solutions: 0
    Solver results file: results.json
[    0.05] Applying Pyomo postprocessing actions
[    0.05] Pyomo Finished
errorcode: 0
retval: instance: <pyomo.core.base.PyomoModel.ConcreteModel object at 0x0000020CD402C9F8>
local:
    time_initial_import: 0.0059854984283447266
    usermodel: <module 'HW5' from 'C:\\Users\\aizuw\\Documents\\Schools\\UTK -\\Classes\\Second Semester\\IE 522\\Assignments\\HW 5\\HW5.py'>
options: <pyomo.common.config.ConfigDict object at 0x0000020CD3F59688>
results: {'Problem': [{'Name': 'unknown', 'Lower bound': -inf, 'Upper bound': inf, 'Number of objectives': 1, 'Number of constraints': 13, 'Number of variables': 37, 'Number of nonzeros': 69, 'Sense': 'minimize'}], 'Solver': [{'Status': 'ok', 'Termination condition': 'unbounded', 'Statistics': {'Branch and bound': {'Number of bounded subproblems': 0, 'Number of created subproblems': 0}}, 'Error rc': 0, 'Time': 0.021906614303588867}]}
```

**THE results.json File OutPut:**

```
{
    "Problem": [
        {
            "Lower bound": -Infinity,
            "Name": "unknown",
            "Number of constraints": 13,
            "Number of nonzeros": 69,
            "Number of objectives": 1,
            "Number of variables": 37,
            "Sense": "minimize",
            "Upper bound": Infinity
        }
    ],
    "Solver": [
        {
            "Error rc": 0,
            "Statistics": {
                "Branch and bound": {
                    "Number of bounded subproblems": 0,
                    "Number of created subproblems": 0
                }
            },
            "Status": "ok",
            "Termination condition": "unbounded",
            "Time": 0.021906614303588867
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is unbounded as constructed because you haven't constrained the domain of the variable, so it is allowed to go negative and the solver is going bonkers because it is trying to model "negative purchases" as well.  This fixes the problem.  (note:  you do not have to initialize the variable either):

```
model.full = Var(fullData, domain=NonNegativeReals)
```

Also, if you work on this a bit, you could tighten up your model construction a bit.  You should be able to work with a list of the RHS values for the constraint and make them all with a loop rather than write them out individually.  Same for your creation of the monthly indices.  Can you think of a math expression for the number of computers on hand in month "n"?  If so, you can make the indices on-the-fly with some list comprehensions and simple conditions.  :)

Comment: Waoooooooo. Thank you very much @AirSquid.  I don't believe it!!!  But that was the issue. I added that domain constraint and it worked. I have spent days on this issue, change my code several times. I marked your response as the answer but I don't have sufficient reputation for it to show up. Thanks Again.